# Python Script to get multi table counts

Tags: python, database

I'm trying to write a python script to get a count of some tables for monitoring which looks a bit like the code below. I'm trying to get an output such as below and have tried using python multi-dimensional arrays but not having any luck.

**Expected Output**:

```
('oltptransactions:', [(12L,)])
('oltpcases:', [(24L,)])
```

**Script**:

```
import psycopg2

# Connection with the DataBase
conn = psycopg2.connect(user = "appuser", database = "onedb", host = "192.168.1.1", port = "5432")
cursor = conn.cursor()

sql = """SELECT COUNT(id) FROM appuser.oltptransactions"""
sql2 = """SELECT count(id) FROM appuser.oltpcases"""

sqls = [sql,sql2]
for i in sqls:
    cursor.execute(i)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    print('Counts:',result)

conn.close()
```

**Current output**:

```
[root@pgenc python_scripts]# python multi_getrcount.py 
('Counts:', [(12L,)])
('Counts:', [(24L,)])
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to print the table names instead of the keyword 'Counts' in the print statements ?

Comment: IF you want to print the count along with table name, then you have to modify your select statement and include your table name as well. cursor.fetachall returns a list of each row as tuples so rather than using fetchall, iterate each row and format your print statement. Such as for name, count in cursor: Print ("")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a bit reluctant to show this way, because best practices recommend to never build a dynamic SQL string but always use a constant string and parameters, but this is one use case where computing the string is legit:

- a table name cannot be a parameter in SQL
- the input only comes from the program itself and is fully mastered

Possible code:

```
sql = """SELECT count(*) from appuser.{}"""
tables = ['oltptransactions', 'oltpcases']

for t in tables:
    cursor.execute(sql.format(t))
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    print("('", t, "':,", result, ")")
```

Comment: Thanks, @Serge Ballesta
I like the table name array and prefer this to hard coding the SELECT statements within the variable. I amended the script to include this change but encountered an error. There's a lot of references to panda when googling for sql.format(table)

` 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 12, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql.format(table))
NameError: name 'table' is not defined

Comment: @ribbit: my bad... I wrote `t` in for and `table` in format :-( Now fixed...

Comment: Thank you!
That's done the trick and appreciate your help.

`[root@pgenc python_scripts]# python a.py `
`("('", 'oltptransactions', "':,", [(12L,)], ')')`
`("('", 'oltpcases', "':,", [(24L,)], ')')`

Answer (score 0):

I believe something as below, Unable to test code because of certificate issue.

```
sql = """SELECT 'oltptransactions', COUNT(id) FROM appuser.oltptransactions"""
sql2 = """SELECT 'oltpcases', COUNT(id) FROM appuser.oltpcases"""

sqls = [sql,sql2]
for i in sqls:
    cursor.execute(i)
    for name, count in cursor:
        print ("")

Or

sql = """SELECT 'oltptransactions :'||COUNT(id) FROM appuser.oltptransactions"""
sql2 = """SELECT 'oltpcases :'||COUNT(id) FROM appuser.oltpcases"""

sqls = [sql,sql2]
for i in sqls:
    cursor.execute(i)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    print(result)
```